# Spring com DataBase (SQLServer) já criada

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *Rest API* utilizando Spring Boot.

Dúvida:
Se eu já tenho uma DataBase em produção com tabelas populadas é necessário criar mesmo assim a classe de Entidade com a anotação `@Entity`.

Se sim é precisa constar todos os campos dessa tabela nessa class ?

Comment: Sim Juliano, o @Entity é para que a classe que vai servir de modelo trabalhe com `javax.persistence.Entity`, sem isso ele não vai entender que aquele classe faz parte de algo, é para persistir, não tem haver com gerar o banco de dados (claro que você pode setar `hbm2ddl.auto` como "create" no hibernate, mas isso é outra história)

Answer (score 0):

Sim Juliano, você deve mapear a classe com o @Entity para definir o objetos persistentes em sua base de dados, você pode mapear os nomes das tabelas e respectivos campos, para os campos que não deseja refletir na base você pode usar a anotação @Transient.

No arquivo de configuração de persistência (xml / properties do Spring Boot) você deve utilizar a estratégia de UPDATE no values ***hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto***.

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=UPDATE

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="UPDATE"/>
```

Esse artigo da algaworks da umas boas dicas sobre JPA: https://blog.algaworks.com/tutorial-jpa/

Comment: Eu fiz essas configurações porém fica aparecendo um erro na criação da class entidade:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'ifuncionario' defined in com.portalDigital7.repository.Ifuncionario defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: Consegue compartilhar o Fonte?

Comment: Oi Paulo postei uma nova pergunta. e coloquei os fontes.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479948/cannot-resolve-reference-to-bean-jpamappingcontext-while-setting-bean-property